can't pass a string array to a function in Powershell
I have the following script called vms.ps1:
# Definições das VMs e grupos
$VMPaths = @{
    "goad1" = "E:\GOAD\ad\GOAD\providers\vmware\.vagrant\machines\GOAD-DC01\vmware_desktop\d293bfc4-dc8c-4e82-9704-1506af10c065\WindowsServer2019.vmx"
    "goad2" = "E:\GOAD\ad\GOAD\providers\vmware\.vagrant\machines\GOAD-DC02\vmware_desktop\73036daa-689c-4ea2-9c3b-86c308990822\WindowsServer2019.vmx"
    "goad3" = "E:\GOAD\ad\GOAD\providers\vmware\.vagrant\machines\GOAD-DC03\vmware_desktop\c3ce3c4a-7e71-4068-8a37-877ac2587d8d\WindowsServer2016.vmx"
    "goad4" = "E:\GOAD\ad\GOAD\providers\vmware\.vagrant\machines\GOAD-SRV02\vmware_desktop\a882d3d0-a4fe-406c-93fb-9c144ba97bab\WindowsServer2019.vmx"
    "goad5" = "E:\GOAD\ad\GOAD\providers\vmware\.vagrant\machines\GOAD-SRV03\vmware_desktop\ef52fe4e-1fa6-48e2-9a27-b0c8bac67454\WindowsServer2016.vmx"
    "syslog" = "F:\vmware\syslog-ng\Syslog-NG.vmx"
    "qradar" = "F:\vmware\QRADAR\QRADAR.vmx"
    "kali" = "F:\vmware\kali-linux-2024.2\kali-linux-2024.2-vmware-amd64.vmx"
    "dockerhub" = "F:\vmware\Docker HUB\Docker HUB.vmx"
    "edr-server" = "F:\vmware\Elastic EDR\Elastic EDR.vmx"
    "flare" = "F:\vmware\FlareVM\FlareVM.vmx"
    "pfsense" = "F:\vmware\pfSense 2.7.0\pfSense 2.7.0.vmx"
    "win22" = "F:\vmware\Win2022\Win2022.vmx"
    "win11-lab1" = "F:\vmware\Win11-Lab1\Win11-Lab1.vmx"
    "win10-lab1" = "F:\vmware\Win10-Lab1\Win10-Lab1.vmx"
}

$VMGroups = @{
    "goad" = @("goad1", "goad2", "goad3", "goad4", "goad5")
    "siem" = @("syslog", "qradar")
    "hardening" = @("syslog", "win22", "pfsense", "win11-lab1", "dockerhub")
}

# Função para listar VMs e grupos
function List-VMs {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "VMs disponíveis:"
    $VMPaths.Keys | ForEach-Object { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $_ }
    
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "`nGrupos disponíveis:"
    
    foreach ($group in $VMGroups.Keys) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "`nGrupo: $group"
        $VMGroups[$group] | ForEach-Object { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "  $_" }
    }
}

# Caminho do vmrun
$vmrunPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun.exe"

# Função para iniciar VMs
function Start-VMs {
    param (
        [string[]]$VMNames
    )
    
    # Verificar se o primeiro parâmetro é um grupo
    if ($VMNames[0] -eq "--group") {
        $groupName = $VMNames[1]
        if ($VMGroups.ContainsKey($groupName)) {
            $VMNames = $VMGroups[$groupName]
        } else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Grupo não encontrado: $groupName"
            return
        }
    }

    # Iniciar VMs
    foreach ($vmAlias in $VMNames) {
        if ($VMPaths.ContainsKey($vmAlias)) {
            $vm = $VMPaths[$vmAlias]
            try {
                & $vmrunPath start $vm
                $vmName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($vm)
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "VM Iniciada: " -NoNewline
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $vmName
            } catch {
                if ($_ -match "is already powered on") {
                    $vmName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($vm)
                    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "VM já está ligada: " -NoNewline
                    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $vmName
                } else {
                    throw $_
                }
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "VM não encontrada: $vmAlias"
        }
    }
}

# Função para suspender VMs
function Suspend-VMs {
    ...
}

# Função para parar VMs
function Stop-VMs {
    ...
}

# Função para desligar VMs
function PowerOff-VMs {
    ...
}

My idea is to run this script from ALIAS in terminal.
My powershell $PROFILE:
. "F:\vmware\vms.ps1"

function vm {
    param (
        [string]$Command,
        [string[]]$VMNames
    )
    
    switch ($Command) {
        "start" { 
            if ($VMNames[0] -eq "--group") {
                Start-VMs -VMNames $VMNames
            } else {
                Start-VMs -VMNames $VMNames
            }
        }
        "suspend" { Suspend-VMs @($VMNames) }
        "stop" { Stop-VMs @($VMNames) }
        "poweroff" { PowerOff-VMs @($VMNames) }
        "list" { List-VMs }
        default { Write-Host "Comando desconhecido: $Command" -ForegroundColor Red }
    }
}

When I run:
vm list: work
vm start syslog: work
vm suspend syslog: work
But:
vm start --group goad: Don't work.
❯ vm start --group goad
MethodInvocationException: F:\vmware\vms.ps1:93
Line |
  93 |          if ($VMGroups.ContainsKey($groupName)) {
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "ContainsKey" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')"
VM não encontrada: --group


I want that when I put:
vm start --group goad
The script starts all VMs that are inside the goad group in $VMGroups.

Only the first argument (--group) is bound to $VMNames. If you want to bind all trailing arguments to a parameter, use a Parameter attribute decorator to set the ValueFromRemainingArguments flag:
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
  [string]$Command
  [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
  [string[]]$VMNames
)

Now, when you do vm start --group goad, both "--group" and "goad" will be added to $VMNames

That's it! It worked! Yesterday, I stayed up until 1 a.m. trying to understand and debug the cause of the error. I tried several ways to pass the complete parameter and didn't know where to go. Thank you for your help.
